# once and for all: deep copying objects

Tags: objective-c

i have seen many attempts to answer this on Stackoverflooooooow and none have satisfied me.

i have a `Person` class with only a public `name` attribute that subclasses `NSObject`. in the `main` i run:

```
Person *alex = [[Person alloc] init];
alex.name = @"alex"
NSLog(@"name: %@ %p", alex.name, alex.name");
```

which will print to the console

```
2015-08-21 21:53:34.047 Test[29456:5960428] name: alex 0x108dfd640
```

the **two** methods i've found for copying both implement the `copyWithZone:` selector from the `<NSCopying>` protocol, which i place this in the `Person` class.

**1)** the first version of this selector is:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *) zone
{
    Person *personCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    personCopy.name = [self.name copyWithZone:zone];
    // i've also tried: personCopy.name = [self.name copy];
    return personCopy;
}
```

in the main i run

```
Person *aCopyOfAlex = [alex copy]
NSLog(@"name: %@ %p", aCopyOfAlex.name, aCopyOfAlex.name");
```

which logs

```
2015-08-21 21:53:34.047 Test[29456:5960428] name: alex 0x108dfd640
```

the `Person` copy instance *is* different but the name attributes for the copy and original point to the *same* place.

**2)** the second version of this selector uses an archiver (which i guess takes some time - especially if i have a lot of attributes to deep copy across?) and then an unarchiver:

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *) zone
{
    Person *personCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    NSData *buffer = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.name];
    personCopy.name = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:buffer];
    return personCopy;
}
```

in the main i run again

```
Person *aCopyOfAlex = [alex copy]
NSLog(@"name: %@ %p", aCopyOfAlex.name, aCopyOfAlex.name");
```

which logs

```
2015-08-21 21:53:34.047 Test[29456:5960428] name: alex 0x7fa80969e4a0
```

this time both the `Person` copy instance *and* the name attribute point to different places.

finally to a question! can someone say which method is correct (if either), please? it seems the second does what i want and would be an actual deep copy..

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your first bit of code. What you are seeing is an optimization done with strings. Since you started with an immutable string literal, copying it simply gives you back the same object. This isn't a problem because it is immutable.

Your second implementation of `Person copyWithZone:` is overkill. Don't bother with the archiving.

Comment: great - highlighting my ignorance since january 2015 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Although I have to agree with @rmaddy about the second one being overkill for this exact case, it is the only one (from the two you are posting) that will perform a deep copy.

Please see [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) for a nice explanation of what deep copying is.

If you had a mutable property say `NSMutableArray *addresses`, the first method would leave you with two `Person` instances sharing the same `NSMutableArray` instances, which means that if you mutate addresses you would see changes in both Person instances, as they are indeed *sharing* the same array.

Please note that the second one will depend on whether the properties in Person are indeed archivable.

Comment: Not quite true. If you copy the `NSMutableArray`, you would not end up sharing the mutable array. You would have two independent arrays. However, you would have two arrays both referencing the same set of shallow copied objects. But the question wasn't about deep/shallow copying of container classes. If it was, I would have given a very different answer.

Comment: i'd have to agree with @rmaddy - but thank you for that link (very helpful conceptually)